# Three views in one line - middle line fill the gap

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have 3 views that I want to be in one line. This views are: TextView View TextView and the should look like this:

```
Today --------- 89
```

Line should fill all the free spaces that is left by this 2 TextViews.
I tried with this code, but line put "89" out of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Today"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/background_seen" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_mail_header_day"
    android:background="@color/background_seen" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_mail_header_line"
    android:text="89"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining a `LinearLayout` with non-zero layout weight:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Today"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/background_seen" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_line"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/background_seen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_mail_header_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="89"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```